# Just installed 12.04 and it freezes when I try logging in

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 on an Acer Aspire 1 with AMD Dual-Core C60, 4 GB RAM, and 320 GB HDD (100 GB partitioned for Ubuntu).  After restarted my computer, I was able to log in fine but when I tried to log in again after shutting my netbook off, it began to freeze on the log in screen.  The freezing occurs several seconds after I'm prompted to enter my password.  Even if i enter the password before the freezing occurs, I end up getting stuck while it's loading or something.  I'm new to Ubuntu so I have no idea what to do.  Also, before it gets to the log in screen, it says something like this:

NTFS5: No wubildr
NTFS5: No wubildr
NTFS5: error: "prefix"

edit: it was wubildr, not unbilder.  Also, the freezing seems to be inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same thing on an Acer Aspire One 722 -

According to reports in various places, the random and irreversible freezes seem to be an issue with the networking/network card. A possible solution: changing the boot order (F12 on startup) to place Network Boot in the first position. Turning of "auto connect" for wlan in network manager might also help.

I've implemented these on my system, and so far it is helping (only a few hours in though).